# has_secure_password and email verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, verification

`has_secure_password` in rails works well for signing up users by checking `:password` and `:password_confirmation` then logging a `:password_digest` field in the database. However, if I want to be able to verify the email address (by sending an email confirmation) how would I be able to do this with rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally to verify an email address, you send an email to the concerned email address ( with a link ) and the user clicks a link / verifies it. The link generally contains a token used to uniquely identify that email address. So you can add a **verification_token** field to your model, may be add **verification_email_sent_at** and **verified_at** fields as well, to keep track and use a controller action

```
   def verify_email
     @user = User.find_by_verification_token(params[:verification_token])
     if @user
        @user.verification_token = nil
        @user.verification_email_sent_at = nil
        @user.verified_at = Time.now
        @user.save
        # above lines can be part of method like @user.verify!
        redirect_to "/"
     else
        ...
     end
   end
```

**Also I'd strongly suggest instead of building your authentication solution take a look at**

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Its pretty simple to use.

Comment: hey Rishav, could you specify how to make the link in the view so that the verification token is sent in the URL? Ie a path like /users/23/verifyemail/34563 where "23" would be the user id, and "34563" the verification token it has been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Rishav Rastogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66945/rishav-rastogi)'s response, make sure you add the appropriate checking to make sure the verification parameter is both sanitized and not null (or else, someone passing in a null verification token can gain access to the account of a user whose `verification_token` column is null.

It would also behove you to utilize the `verified_at` column in your secure checking.

(I can't comment on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172781/4241192) due to lack of reputation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big question, and I'm not sure it has anything to do with `has_secure_password`. The gist is you will want a field on your user model, say `confirmed`, and make a mailer which sends the confirmation email, which has a link to a controller which will mark the user as confirmed.

I suggest you check out the [`ActionMailer guide`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) to get started.

Comment: This does't work !! Because has_secure_password doesn't allow to change a user object without changing the user's password and password confirmation ... I have done the same thing as @rfunduk described. And I'm stuck. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your issue? `has_secure_password` has no opinion on the way in which you change your user object... If you change `password` you must supply `password_confirmation` at the same time, that is the only requirement I am aware of.